# Swing JButton , Java programing

Tags: java, swing

program suppose to run "Guess the number" game 
after guessing the number correctly , there's an option to start over

Pressing the "playAgainBtn" make the program stuck.
Another issue is after guessing the "guessText" cant be .selectAll

any insight will be welcomed

Tnx.

```
public class GuessTheNumberGame extends JFrame
{
    private int randomNumber;
    private boolean correctGuess;
    private JLabel startMsg;
    private JLabel enterGuessJLabel;
    private JButton playAgainBtn;
    private JLabel msgToPlayer;
    private JTextField guessText;
    private int previousGuess; // previous guessed number hot/cold
    private int numOfGuess;
    private Container container;
    public GuessTheNumberGame()
    {
        container = getContentPane();
        startMsg = new JLabel();
        enterGuessJLabel = new JLabel();
        guessText = new JTextField(10);
        guessText.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                    {
                        int  playerGuess = Integer.parseInt(event.getActionCommand());
                        if ( playerGuess == randomNumber )
                        {
                            msgToPlayer.setText("Great ! u guessed in " + numOfGuess + "Guesses");
                            correctGuess = true;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            wrongGuess(playerGuess);
                        }
                    }

                }
                );
        msgToPlayer = new JLabel("");
        playAgainBtn = new JButton("Play Again");
        ButtonHandler buttonHandler = new ButtonHandler();
        playAgainBtn.addActionListener(buttonHandler);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(startMsg);
        add(enterGuessJLabel);
        add(guessText);
        add(msgToPlayer);
        add(playAgainBtn);

    }

    protected class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener 
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            startGame();
        }

    }

    public void startGame()
    {
        previousGuess = 1000;
        numOfGuess = 1;
        correctGuess = false;
        Random rand = new Random();
        randomNumber = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
        startMsg.setText( "I have a number between 1 and 1000. can you Guess my Number?" );
        playAgainBtn.setVisible( false );

        while ( !correctGuess)
        {
            enterGuessJLabel.setText( "Please enter your " + numOfGuess + " guess: " );
        }

        playAgainBtn.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void wrongGuess(int playerGuess)
    {
        numOfGuess++;
        if ( Math.abs(playerGuess - randomNumber) > previousGuess )
                container.setBackground( Color.GREEN);
        else 
            container.setBackground( Color.RED);
        previousGuess = Math.abs(playerGuess - randomNumber);

        if (playerGuess > randomNumber)
            msgToPlayer.setText("Too High");
        else 
            msgToPlayer.setText( "Too Low" );
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to put it more meaningfully... `Program stuck`?? What is the error. Did you check the stacktrace in console output

Comment: Tnx for the comment , i'll more specific in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start the application, startGame() runs on the *main* thread, which is OK.  When you press playAgainBtn, it calls startGame() on the *AWT Dispatch Thread*, thus tying up this thread, prohibiting the AWT from processing events.  Try this to free up the AWT Dispatch Thread:

```
protected class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener 
{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public final void run() {
                startGame();
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your startGame method, called when the button is clicked, has an infinite loop in it.

```
while ( !correctGuess)
    {
        enterGuessJLabel.setText( "Please enter your " + numOfGuess + " guess: " );
    }
```

The correctGuess variable will never be changed so your program will just execute the setText command endlessly.

The way Swing (and all GUI frameworks) work is that you must always respond to an event such as a button click and then return control.

Comment: Tnx 4 the helpful explanation. Driven by events exclude the need of looping.